# Rewrite scr of images with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an images with not correct first part of src. For example `artweb-it.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/block-02s.png` has to be `artweb.su/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/block-02s.png` so I basically want to rewrite artweb-it.ru to artweb.su with htaccess but I don't know anything about rewriting.
Please, help me figuring this out

Here is htaccess rules file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please do share your htaccess rules file in your question, thank you.

Comment: i've edited my question